# How to Upload the image and Video in two Different Folder using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fresher in codeignite and I want to Upload the image and video into image and video folder. But image and video uploaded into the same folder.

I tried so many times using if condition, but nothing is changed.

Please help to solve this problem.

Here is my code:-

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['data'] = "";
        $data['content']=$this->load->view('cmsblock/cmsblock',$data,TRUE);
        $this->load->view('includes/main',$data);
    }

    function do_upload()
    {    


        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {

            if (!empty($value['tmp_name'])) {


                if($key == "file1") {

                    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|3gp|gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
                    $config['max_size']='';
                    $config['max_width']='200000000';
                    $config['max_height']='1000000000000';
                    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    //failed display the errors
                    } else {

                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        $this->load->view('cmsblock/success', $data);

                    }
                }
                if($key == "file2") {

                    $config11['upload_path'] = 'videos';
                    //$config11['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
                    $config11['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|3gp|gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
                    $config11['max_size']='';
                    $config11['max_width']='200000000';
                    $config11['max_height']='1000000000000';
                    $this->load->library('upload',$config11);
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    //failed display the errors
                    } else {

                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        $this->load->view('cmsblock/success', $data);

                    }
                }               



            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Here is my HTML file code:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="file1" id="file_1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file_2"/>
<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: without your form html code, it's difficult to decide!!!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$this->upload->initialize($config11);
```

instead of

```
$this->load->library('upload',$config11);
```

in `if($key == "file2"){...`  part